# PHP: How can i put JSON to Menu

Tags: php, json

I have a Json for menu i savved it like :-

```
[{"slug":"index.php","name":"Home"},{"slug":"aboutus","name":"About us","children":[{"slug":"eims","name":"Eims"},{"slug":"vision","name":"Vision"}]},{"slug":"trash","name":"Trash","children":[{"slug":"ways","name":"Ways­"},{"slug":"requ","name":"Requ"}]}]
```

Now i need to convert this json to menu like this :-

```
<li><a href="./"  >Home</a></li>
<li><a href="container.php?fun=aboutus" >About us</a>       
            <ul>
                <li><a href="container.php?fun=eims">Eims</a></li>
                <li><a href="container.php?fun=vision">Vision</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
<li><a href="container.php?fun=trash">Trash</a>
<ul>
                <li><a href="container.php?fun=ways­">Ways­</a></li>
                <li><a href="container.php?fun=requ">Requ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</li>
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: decode it, loop through printing elements out, check for children, loop through and print out those

Comment: Which language are you using to generate the HTML?

Comment: if this is just a simple and fixed leveled data, then you don't really need a recursive function, just loop it straight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out.

```
<?php
    function parseNodes($nodes) {
            $ul = "<ul>\n";
            foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                    $ul .= parseNode($node);
            }
            $ul .= "</ul>\n";
            return $ul;
    }

    function parseNode($node) {
            $li = "\t<li>";
            $li .= '<a href="'.$node->slug.'">'.$node->name.'</a>';
            if (isset($node->children)) { $li .= parseNodes($node->children); }
            $li .= "</li>\n";
            return $li;
    }


    $json = '[{"slug":"index.php","name":"Home"},{"slug":"aboutus","name":"About us","children":[{"slug":"eims","name":"Eims"},{"slug":"vision","name":"Vision"}]},{"slug":"trash","name":"Trash","children":[{"slug":"ways","name":"Ways­"},{"slug":"requ","name":"Requ"}]}]';

    $nodes = json_decode($json);

    $html = parseNodes($nodes);

    echo $html;
?>
```